# "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered" PHP

Tags: php, str-replace, number-formatting

I am getting the following error as a result of a calculation. I couldn't see any problem with the exit code. So why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

```
// b2Cost = 19.020843;

return (float)number_format((float)str_replace(",", ".", $b2Cost), 2, ".", "");
```

Error:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Comment: Why do you `number_format` in between there, and then cast that to `(float)` again?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/f9Iqe you're getting a notice, but it still works as expected. It's letting you know that [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is expecting a string as the 3rd parameter, but you're passing a float. So it's converting it to a string and continuing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I guess there is no way to turn off this notification except `display_errors` @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: Or, like the answer below suggests, convert this to a string before the function gets called. A quick and dirty way is `str_replace(",", ".", $b2Cost."")`, which is functionally the same as `str_replace(",", ".", (string) $b2Cost)` or `str_replace(",", ".", strval($b2Cost))`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I understand, thanks you for your time and comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```php
return (float)number_format((float)str_replace(",", ".", (string) $b2Cost), 2, ".", "");
```

But if you just want to shorten the float, take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: For clarification to readers, `str_replace` calls for a string subject, but `$b2Cost` is instantiated as an integer. The answer here [typecasts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the integer variable as a string, using `(string)$b2Cost`, to satisfy `str_replace` requirements. (Guido, best to explain your answer.)